# Is it possible to add C# to Coded UI data source or UIMap.uitest files?

Tags: c#, automation, coded-ui-tests

Suppose that I have a Coded UI test that I want to data drive.

My application under test has a date field and the date field only supports dates that are >= the current date. Is it possible to add C# code in my data source so that the dates are generated from C# code?

For example:

```
 DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
 DateTime.Now.AddDays(90).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

If this is not possible, can C# be entered into the UIMap.uitest? When I enter the code, the test picks the code up as a string. I can enter the C# code into the designer file but 1) this will get overwritten often and 2) this wouldn't allow me to do multiple options.

Answer (score 2):

The `UIMap.uitest` is backed by two files, one is the designer file which you should leave alone as you already stated because it will get generated again.

The second file is the `UIMap.cs` which is the partial class of the class that is generated in the desginer file.

Every generated method comes with a [Methodname]Params class that holds the properties that are used in that particular method. To bring in dynamic data you could do the folowing.

In `UIMap.cs` add this (assuming you have a RecordedMethod1)

```
    public partial class UIMap
    {
        public void RecordedMethod1(DateTime date)
        {
            RecordedMethod1Params.YourDate = date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

            RecordedMethod1();
        }
    }
```

Now in your `CodedUiTest` class `TestMethod1` use the now created overload for RecordedMethod1

```
 this.UIMap.RecordedMethod1(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-90));
```

Comment: Thanks, this will work for one scenario. Suppose I want to cycle the test 10 times and in every cycle I want to choose a different date generated from C# code, do you have an idea as to how this can be implemented? Do you think perhaps an array can be created to hold multiple C#-generated dates?

Answer (score 0):

Coded UI tests can be data driven, that is often thought of as getting data from a data file such as a CSV file or a spread sheet. But the ideas of data driving can be used in other ways. Your tests need one part of data driving but the data source is the system clock.

When you record part of a test and save it as a method, any values entered are used as the initial values of fields in a class with a name based on the method name. For an action method named `MyMethod` the class will be `MyMethodParams`. For a method that checks assertions in method named `MyAssertion` the class will be `MyAssertionExpectedValues`. When the method runs it uses values from the `...Params` or the `...ExpectedValues` class. These values can be overwritten before calling the method.

For your test where each execution of the test should use a different date and time you can write code such as

```
MyMethodParams.DateField = DateTime.Now.AddDays(90).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
MyMethodParams.TimeField = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff");
MyMethod();
```

If each test iteration requires a different date then you could add the test iteration number to the `90` used above. The iteration could easily be counted via a `static int` of the class.

The Coded UI content index has links to data driving Coded UI tests and to many other useful topics. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mathew_aniyan/archive/2013/02/18/content-index-for-coded-ui-test.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would approach this:

For the sake of simplicity and repeatability and clarity it would be simpler to create a data source (e.g. an XML file) with the various dates you want to test and use that to populate the method params in your tests.

When you run your test, it will rerun for every data row you've got in your data source. So if you've got 10 date entries, it'll run 10 times.

Put the following code in your CodedUI test.
This will define the data source (data.xml) that your test is going to read from.

```
[DeploymentItem("MyTest\\data.xml"), DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML", "|DataDirectory|\\data.xml", "Entry", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), TestMethod]
```

The data.xml will look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Data>
  <Entry>
   <Date>2013/01/01</Date>
  </Entry>
  <Entry>
   <Date>2013/03/11</Date>
  </Entry>
  <Entry>
   <Date>2013/04/11</Date>
  </Entry>
  <Entry>
   <Date>2013/06/17</Date>
  </Entry>
</Data>
```

Here you will want to modify the params of your recorded method to read from the data.xml data source.

```
this.UIMap.RecordedMethodParams.UITxtDateEditText =TestContext.DataRow["Date"].ToString();
this.UIMap.RecordedMethod();
```

When you run the CodedUI test when it gets to your RecordedMethod it will run it once for every date entry you have in your data source. You can have 1 or 10,000.

I like this method because it allows you to modify a simple XML any time you want to change the parameters of your test. This also allows non-skilled testers to change the test to their requirements without having to dabble in the code.

I hope this helps!